# How to drop new elements if an observer is busy?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have an observable which regularly emits elements. On those elements, I perform one fast and one slow operation. What I want is to drop new elements for slow observer while it is busy. Is there any way to achieve this with Rx instead of keeping a flag in slow operation?

I am very new at Reactive extensions, please correct me if anything is wrong with my assumptions.

```swift
let tick = Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(1), 
            scheduler: SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background)).share()

tick.subscribe {
    print("fast observer \($0)")
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)

// observing in another queue so that it does not block the source
tick.observeOn(SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
    .subscribe {
        print("slow observer \($0)")
        sleep(3) // cpu-intensive task
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, flatMap is your friend. Whenever you want to drop events (either the current one when a new one comes in, or subsequent ones while working on the current one) use flatMap. More information can be found in my article: [RxSwift’s Many Faces of FlatMap](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/rxswifts-many-faces-of-flatmap-5764e6c2018c)

Here you go:

```
let tick = Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(1), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).share()

func cpuLongRunningTask(_ input: Int) -> Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        print("start task")
        sleep(3)
        print("finish task")
        observer.onNext(input)
        observer.onCompleted()
        return Disposables.create { /* cancel the task if possible */ }
    }
}

tick
    .subscribe {
        print("fast \($0)")
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

tick
    .flatMapFirst {
        // subscribing in another scheduler so that it does not block the source
        cpuLongRunningTask($0)
            .subscribeOn(SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
    }
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance) // make sure the print happens on the main thread
    .subscribe {
        print("slow \($0)")
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Sample output as follows:

```
fast next(0)
start task
fast next(1)
fast next(2)
fast next(3)
finish task
slow next(0)
fast next(4)
start task
fast next(5)
fast next(6)
fast next(7)
finish task
slow next(4) <-- slow ignored the 1, 2, and 3 values.
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know flatMapFirst. But, when I try this with a cpu intensive long running task, it does not work same, even if I call it in Observable.create closure. My intention in using sleep is not to delay result but to block thread.

Comment: If it isn't working, then it's because your "cpu intensive long running task" is built incorrectly and the Observable is completing before the task is finished.

Comment: I updated the code sample to show how to write your "cpu intensive long running task".

Comment: Oh, I got it. My mistake was to observe it with observeOn background scheduler, instead of subscribeOn in flatMapFirst. Thanks a lot, I'll definitely check out your articles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is not a straightforward solution. The issue you describe is related to backpressure and unfortunately, RxSwift does not provide support for it (Apple Combine does). Usually, you will have to handle this situation manually by using one of the filtering operators: `debounce`, `throttle` or `filter`.
By using `debounce` or `throttle` you would need to know the exact duration of the operation which probably is not always the case.
By using `filter`, as you said, you could check for a flag you set before starting the long-running operation.